# Running python3 using a Run/Debug config with Vagrant: "Error running x.py Can't run remote python interpreter"

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm

I get the following PyCharm error when running my python3 interpreter on Vagrant:

> Error running x.py Can't run remote python interpreter: The provider for this   Vagrant-managed machine is reporting that it is not yet ready for SSH. Depending on your provider this can carry different meanings. Make sure your machine is created and running and try again. Additionally, check the output of `vagrant status` to verify that the machine is in the state that you expect. If you continue to get this error message, please view the documentation for the provider you're using.

I have no problem running the code from the terminal. I only have a problem when running through my Run/Debug Configuration.

Using PyCharm 2016.3.1 on Windows 10.
PyCharm

How do I run from my Run/Debug Configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was only changing the project python interpreter configuration to point to my running Vagrant machine, however, the Run/Debug Configuration wasn't set to use this project interpreter, but rather a different Vagrant machine which was currently down.

Fixed by editing the Run/Debug Configuration and changing the "Python interpreter" to "Project Default".